# Weird rendering of .html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout

So I have this file:

```
<h1>Calendar view</h1>

<div class="events">
    <% @events.each do |e| %>
        <%= raw(e.content)%>
    <% end %>
</div>


<br />
<div class="messages">
    <% @messages.each do |m| %>
        <%= raw(m.content)%>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

With @events and @messages being valid instance variables in the controller...but when I go to the page the html looks like this:

```
<h1>Calendar view</h1>

<div class="events">
    <br>
      <div class="messages">
        This is another message test
      </div
    Event Content

</div>
```

I'm confused. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: So what is *in* @messages and @events? (i.e. what does `raw(e.content)` output on its own?

Comment: HTML content input by an admin/me. So the only thing in @events is html. And e.content outputs in this case a very small table, and messages outputs this is another message test.

Comment: `raw` is definitely the way to go, but my guess is that the HTML is somewhere incomplete and when mixed in the template engine, it causes quite a confusion. Maybe you could supply the original content of `e.content` in your question for us to see.

Comment: Ah you sir are correct. I had forgotten the closing </table> tag in the html content....doh. Anyways if you want to write a version of your comment above into an answer I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `raw()` will output raw HTML content. The Rails template engine will try to merge that with the `.erb` template you supplied.

Therefore, if either `m.content` or `e.content` are malformed, you will most likely get unexpected output.

The best way would be to look for syntax errors, especially missing closing elements.